# Vevo content using Android YouTubePlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api

Recently, I've been trying to play some Vevo Justin Bieber videos using a special Google library for [Youtube playback](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

In order to play video files, their ids are retrieved via the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
?part=snippet
&maxResults=20
&q=ENCODED_JUSTIN_BIEBER_STRING
&type=video
&key=API_KEY
```

... and queued into the `YouTubePlayer`:

```
player.cueVideo(vevoId);
```

... and when it comes to playing Vevo's Justin Bieber the `YouTubePlayerView` gives me this message:

> This video contains content from VEVO. its restricted from playback on
>   certain sites.... Watch on Youtube.

Does it mean that Vevo's video content can not be played with the Google's library?

Are there any additional steps to take in order to accomplish playing the vevo video files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the restriction on devices. Here are some forums that discuss the same error you experienced: [Cannot play VEVO videos](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/issues/28) which states that

> "VEVO appears to have embed restrictions based on device, so they must be checking the user-agent of the web view. Unfortunately I don't believe there's much way around this without spoofing the user-agent, and I don't particularly want to force everyone who uses this library to break the YouTube/VEVO terms of service by bypassing their content embedding restrictions."

and [Contents from VEVO, SME and UGM cannot be played on certain sites](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/g8nSHHKvH5I/PRagdQlUuWsJ). I hope this helps.